# Android Studio: Proguard and modules

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I have an app that has another Android project added as a Module, so my main App Gradle files has

```
compile project(':anotherAndroidProject')
```

My question is, if my main app Gradle files is configured to run proguard, and also the other project is configured to run proguard, will both projects run their own proguard files as defined in each project folder?

Also, if I have:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
```

Do I need to add proguard rules specific to this external source, or can I assume that they have a ProGuard file with their source which will automatically keep any classes necessary?

Comment: U have it right . Both apks  ( proj1, p2 ) have respective files controlling the minify/ obfuscate process . Com.fb.android IMO will not drag along its own      .  You have  to account for those psckages in your proguard config. Its open source . Its ok to bypass them i